# Automapper map to nullable DateTime property

Tags: c#, automapper

using Automapper 3.1.1 I can not compile this map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.DomainObjects.Entities.Patient, PatientDto>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Deleted, opt => opt.MapFrom(input => input.Deleted.HasValue ? 
                    new DateTime(input.Deleted.Value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc) : null ));
```

Error:

`Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'DateTime'`

Entity:

```
public class Patient : Entity
{
        // more properties
        public virtual DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Feel like I am missing something obvious but can not figure out what exactly.

note: Dto contains `DateTime? Deleted` too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't tested, but you should just need to explicitly cast `null` to a `DateTime?`.  (`(DateTime?)null`)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.DomainObjects.Entities.Patient, PatientDto>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Deleted, opt => opt.MapFrom(input => input.Deleted == null ? (DateTime?)null : (
                new DateTime(input.Deleted.Value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc))));
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I had the same problem with a custom AutoMapper. My DTO property was DateTime? but my entity property was DateTime. I mapped the property as follows: _dto.DateOfAchievement = (entity.DateOfAchievement == DateTime.MinValue) ? (DateTime?)null : entity.DateOfAchievement

Answer (score 2):

Just cast the new `DateTime` to `DateTime?`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.DomainObjects.Entities.Patient, PatientDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Deleted, opt => opt.MapFrom(input => input.Deleted.HasValue ? 
                (DateTime?) new DateTime(input.Deleted.Value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc) : null ));
```